# Where can I download copyforbuild.bat?

Tags: powershell

I am interested in a power shell script that will do a recursive search for files using a filename pattern.

I thought I would find it with Copyforbuild.bat, but I cannot find where I can download it or copy the source code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is copyforbuild.bat and what does it do? What exactly are you looking for here, and what have you done to attempt to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gci -Path "C:\tasks" -recurse -Filter "*rspc*.doc*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-File c:\temp\rspc9.txt

This command when entered into PowerShell will look for a file with the pattern *rspc*.doc* that is in C:\Tasks and all folders underneath it.  It redirects the output to a file.

If there is a folder with a long name or there is some other error, then it will continue to search, ignoring the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what copyforbuild.bat is, if that is from an application, but that is not a powershell script. If you are looking for a file recursively you can use Get-ChildItem (or GCI for short).

```
gci -Path C:\ -Recursive -Filter somefile.ext
```

That would search the whole C:\ drive for a file named "somefile.ext". If that doesn't solve what you are trying to do, could you be more specific as to what you are looking for?

If you need to match patterns then you probably want to use a Regular Expression (RegEx). I'm not sure how powershell will deal with "too long" folders (over 256 character path length), but in general you could do:

```
gci -Path C:\ -Recursive | ? {$_.Name -match "<RegEx Pattern>"}
```

For more information on RegEx see http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html

Comment: I am trying to find all of the files that match a certain pattern within a directory and all child directories underneath.  My problem is that one or more directories have names that are too long.  I would prefer to do this using Power Shell.  Thanks for the help.